# Not able to cache fqueries in a bool filter using Nest 1.0

Tags: caching, elasticsearch, nest

I have a requirement of caching fqueries inside a `bool` `should`/`must` filter. Example: I want to produce the following ES query string using Nest. I've used term and wildcard queries simply as placeholders here. They can be any generic queries.

```
"filter": {
    "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "term": {
                        "field1": {
                           "value": "value1"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            },
            {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "wildcard": {
                        "field2": {
                           "value": "value2"
                        }
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
```

I could not find any Nest documentation around this and in Nest code I only found how to cache the entire bool query but not individual fqueries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filed an issue for this and an UT has been added to demonstrate the same. Find the UT [here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Nest.Tests.Unit/Reproduce/Reproduce928Tests.cs).